# Ubuntu 18.04: Couldn't load SIP module qgis

Tags: 18.04, qgis

I am trying to install QGIS on Ubuntu 18.4 so I added this repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally updated my sources and I installed QGis:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis
```

but when running the application i got these errors:

```
groot@groot-Product:~$ qgis
"<font color=\"red\">Couldn't load SIP module.<br>Python support will be disabled.</font><br><pre><br>Traceback (most recent call last):<br>&nbsp; File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module><br>&nbsp; File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/__init__.py\", line 72, in <module><br>&nbsp; &nbsp; from qgis.PyQt import QtCore<br>&nbsp; File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/QtCore.py\", line 26, in <module><br>&nbsp; &nbsp; from PyQt5.QtCore import *<br>ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12' not found (required by /home/groot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so)<br><br></pre>Python version:<br>3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) <br>[GCC 8.2.0]<br><br>QGIS version:<br>3.4.6-Madeira 'Madeira', exported<br><br>Python path:<br>['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/groot/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python', '/home/groot/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/groot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']"
"<font color=\"red\">An error occurred during execution of following code:<br><tt>qgis.utils.uninstallErrorHook()</tt></font><br><pre><br>Traceback (most recent call last):<br>&nbsp; File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module><br>NameError: name 'qgis' is not defined<br><br></pre>Python version:<br>3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) <br>[GCC 8.2.0]<br><br>QGIS version:<br>3.4.6-Madeira 'Madeira', exported<br><br>Python path:<br>['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/groot/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python', '/home/groot/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/groot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']"
```

And after I exit the application I got these error:

```
"<font color=\"red\">An error occurred during execution of following code:<br><tt>qgis.utils.uninstallErrorHook()</tt></font><br><pre><br>SystemError: PyEval_EvalCodeEx: NULL globals<br><br></pre>Python version:<br><br><br>QGIS version:<br>3.4.6-Madeira 'Madeira', exported<br><br>Python path:<br>"
groot@groot-Product:~$
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem so i answered to my question to someone stuck in my situation:

According [this page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129615/pyqt5-not-finding-installed-qt5-library):

> PyQt in PyPI is not compatible with the installed Qt

So I removed pyqt5 using pip3:

```
pip3 uninstall PyQt5
```

and installed PyQt5 from apt:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

Now Qgis seems to work correctly.

Comment: Wonderful! Finally, your solution worked for me, after weeks of looking. If anyone is wondering why they have a "permission denied" error, you might have to use `sudo pip3 uninstall PyQt5`.
In my case, I didn't have to install python3-pyqt5, as I already had the latest version installed. Not sure if removing the pip3 version of PyQt5 broke anything on my system, but will make sure I let people know here.

Comment: make sure to run `pip3 uninstall PyQt5` as a normal user **not** as `root`. Sometimes you will also have to uninstall it for older Python versions via `pip3 uninstall PyQt5`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i solved my problem on Ubuntu 20.04 and QGIS "a coruña"

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on Manjaro / ArchLinux.

I had noticed that I don't get this error with `sudo qgis`, but this isn't a good solution because I want to use my home directory, not root's. Hints that permissions and paths are off somehow.

```
pip uninstall PyQt5 # defaults to pip3
sudo pacman -S python-pyqt5 python-pyqt5-sip
```

Now QGIS launches python successfully.